# Trying to find Generalization of Product rule when selections are dependent

Tags: combinatorics

Given these sets.

$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $B = \{3, 4, 5\}$,  $C = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

I'm trying to apply a formula for the inclusion exclusion principle in finding the number of triplets with distinct entries.

I got the following: $|A||B||C| - |A \cap B||C| - |A \cap C||B| - |B \cap C||A| + |A \cap B \cap C| = 22.$

But when I count the number triplets by hand I get 24.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think you excluded $|A\cap B \cap C|$ one extra time...

Comment: Why should I include it twice? Can you give me the general formula for the product rule?

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1$ be the set of selections where the 1st and 2nd numbers are the same,

let $E_2$ be the set of selections where the 1st and 3rd numbers are the same, and

let $E_3$ be the set of selections where the 2nd and 3rd numbers are the same.

Using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,

$|\overline{E_1}\cap\overline{E_2}\cap\overline{E_3}|=|S|-|E_1|-|E_2|-|E_3|+|E_1\cap E_2|+|E_1\cap E_3|+|E_2\cap E_3|-|E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3|$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=48-8-12-8+2+2+2-2=24.$